# Moving several files from one bucket to another in AWS returns error: Timed Out

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, s3cmd

I'm using s3cmd to copy over 5000 files from one bucket to a folder within another bucket.

Like this:

```
s3cmd mv --recursive -v s3://test.bucket/1111_stuff/ s3://actual.bucket/input/dataloader_input/
```

However, this keeps getting me this:

> INFO: Retrieving list of remote files for s3://dataloader.bucket/1111_stuff/ ...
>   INFO: Summary: 5186 remote files to move
>   ERROR: timed out

It is stuck on `Retrieving list of remote files` for quite some time, and all I got out of it was an error.

Is this a problem on AWS side, or is it something I can fix? Is there any other way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the socket is timing out, you might want to try changing the value of `socket_timeout` to `180` which is about 3 minutes, in your `.s3cfg`

And if the above, does not help, you might want to read some similar questions

[Can I move a file into a 'folder' inside an S3 bucket using the s3cmd mv command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11049354/can-i-move-a-file-into-a-folder-inside-an-s3-bucket-using-the-s3cmd-mv-command?rq=1)

[s3cmd failed too many times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5774808/s3cmd-failed-too-many-times)